# Compiling PHP on OS X: iconv works only if forced to 64-bit

Tags: php, macos, 64-bit, compile

I'm trying to compile PHP and I kept getting this error during `make`:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      __php_iconv_mime_decode in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strlen in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_string in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strpos in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_substr in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_stream_filter_factory_create in iconv.o
      ...
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      __php_iconv_mime_decode in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strlen in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_string in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strpos in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_substr in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_stream_filter_dtor in iconv.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The `./configure` command of PHP has the iconv folder pointing to `/opt/local`, so the macport iconv library is used (which is installed using the the `+universal` flag). Doing `file` I get:

```
/opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib (for architecture i386):  Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
/opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

I tried then install the iconv library manually, forcing only the 64-bit architecture (I installed it in `/usr/local`) and it works. The output of `file` is:

```
/usr/local/lib/libiconv.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Why is this happening? 
I manage to build and make PHP work with the manual installation, but I don't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MacPorts iconv library renames the symbols to `_libiconv_open` and `_libiconv_close`. That's why PHP couldn't find them, not because of the forced 64-bit. Run `nm /opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib` vs `nm /usr/lib/libiconv.dylib` (in 10.7.3).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it working by pointing PHP to the non-macports version using --with-iconv-dir=/usr/lib

Answer (score 0):

In my case `--with-iconv-dir=/usr/lib` was not enough, I think this option don't work. So I manually renamed `/opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib` to `/opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib.bak` and after building renamed back.